# How to create a top level xaml that mimic a windows in wpf

Tags: css, wpf, xaml

I want to create a window that I can style its shape (for example close button). Based on my reading I can not style these sections of a windows as they are not client sections and they are handeled by OS.

To create my own winmdows style, I created a border less windows( style=none) and I am trying to place the buttons on window by myself.

In my design the top of window should have an image on left hand side and close/minimize/maximise buttons on right.

I have this xaml which would shows logo on left and a button on right.

```
<DockPanel>
        <DockPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="50" Background="DarkGray" Width="Auto" cal:Message.Attach="[Event MouseLeftButtonDown] = [Action MoveWindow]">
            <Image  DockPanel.Dock="left" Height="47" Source="/Resources/Images/Toplogo.png"/>
            <Button  DockPanel.Dock="Right" Width="16" Height="14" x:Name="CloseWindow" />
</DockPanel>
```

But when I run the application, I can see that the logo is on left, but close button is not on the right, but it is in the middle and if I change the window size, logo and button move to the middle of window ( the dockpanel is not resize.)

How can I create such behaviour in xaml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DockPanel defaults to `LastChildFill="True"' so the final element within the DockPanel (your button) fills the remaining space.

You can fix it by adding `HorizontalAlignment="Right"` to the button, or `LastChildFill="False"` to the inner DockPanel.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a `Grid` and create two rows. One for the "window bar" and the other for the "content".
Example:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <!-- Header w/ button -->
    <Grid Grid.Row="0" Background="DarkGray" Height="50" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Image Height="47" Source="/Resources/Images/Toplogo.png" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <Button Width="16" Height="14" x:Name="CloseWindow" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>

    <!-- Body of Window -->
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">

    </Grid>
</Grid>
```